# Como evitar estouro de array em C++?

Tags: array, c++, memória

Meu programa estava apresentando um comportamento esquisito, até que eu descobri que estava havendo um estouro de *array*, por exemplo:

```
int arr[3];
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    arr[i]=i;
    cout << arr[i];
}
```

Neste exemplo claro, `i` ultrapassa o limite de apenas 3 elementos do *array*.

Entretanto o C++ não avisa nada e o programa vai literalmente detonando a memória, gerando comportamentos imprevisíveis no programa.

Como é possível fazer com que o C++ avise (e evite) quando ocorre isto?

Comment: Assim como @Maniero falou, o melhor será usar um built in iterator ou comparar com o tamanho do array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programando em C++ em vez de programar em C. O que você está fazendo é C e não C++. Funciona porque C++ tenta manter compatibilidade com C, mas não é o mais adequado.

Utilize um [`array`, ou um `vector`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101), ou algo parecido. E use um iterador que garante que não poderá ir além dos limites ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282765/101), [outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9446/101), [mais um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100958/101), [com `string`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293230/101), [um simplificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296813/101), [exemplo com e sem iterador mas ainda seguro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126093/101), [um último](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11106/101)).

Existem ferramentas externas que podem analisar e **tentar** informar que tem um erro.

Se quer mais garantias, troque de linguagem. C++ é poderosa, flexível e performática, mas não a mais segura que existe. Ela exige que o programador saiba o que está fazendo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a solução do Maniero.

Isso é um problema de **semântica dinâmica**, no qual só é possível saber se vai gerar um erro critico durante a execução, logo não se torna uma responsabilidade do compilador, visto que essa falha não impede a compilação e nem a execução do programa.

Não se trata de um erro e sim de um *acesso não confiável a um pedaço de memória não alocada pela variável*.

[Neste artigo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/accessing-array-bounds-ccpp/) é possível visualizar que é possível acessar uma area de memória fora dos limites do array, porém não é possível escrever nela.